# Hebrew in Lualatex

Tags: luatex

I am using a Mac (High Sierra 10.13.6) and TexShop (version 5.10) as editor.

I am writing articles in Italian with extensive quotations in Ancient Greek and Hebrew, I use the Polyglossia package and I typeset in Lualatex.

Ancient Greek works fine on TexShop (by some reason not on Overleaf online).

Hebrew is a problem:

When type or I copy and paste e.g. from this link
https://www.bibbiaedu.it/ the text looks fine in the source
but in the pdf letters appears in reverse order: left to right while  Hebrew should  written right to left. Moreover accents are shifted of one step.

The minimal example is at the end of the message.

I also join a screenshot of the resulting pdf.

[![as you see letters appear in reverse order ][1]][1]

Also I had to remove the command `%\setotherlanguage{hebrew}`
because I got the error message:

```
Module polyglossia Warning: Language hebrew not found in language.dat.lua on in
put line 21

./esempio.aux:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \select@language {italian}
```

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=poly]{greek}
%\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}

 Italian :Nel mezzo del cammino di nostra vita 
 
 Greek: 
ὅτι καὶ τῆς ἐκτὸς γωνίας ἐπ' ἄπειρον αὐξηθῆναι δυναμένης καὶ μειωθῆναι

 
 Hebrew: 

20,2 וַיַּסֵּ֥ב אֶת־פָּנָ֖יו אֶל־הַקִּ֑יר וַיִּ֨תְפַּלֵּ֔ל אֶל־יְהוָ֖ה לֵאמֹֽ
 

looks fine in the source file , but is printed reversed in the pdf 

\end{document}
```

According to a suggestion on Overleaf I changed the font specifications and it works now fine there.
I still have problems in Tex Shop.
Below the code and the copy and paste of the message error.
(Is there any way to load Hebrew ?) Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{SBL Hebrew}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=poly]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}

 Italian :Nel mezzo del cammino di nostra vita 
 greek:
 \textreek {
ὅτι καὶ τῆς ἐκτὸς γωνίας ἐπ' ἄπειρον αὐξηθῆναι δυναμένης καὶ μειωθῆναι
}
 Hebrew: 
\texthebrew
{
2 וַיַּסֵּ֥ב אֶת־פָּנָ֖יו אֶל־הַקִּ֑יר וַיִּ֨תְפַּלֵּ֔ל אֶל־יְהוָ֖ה לֵאמֹֽ
}

\begin{hebrew}
20,2 וַיַּסֵּ֥ב אֶת־פָּנָ֖יו אֶל־הַקִּ֑יר וַיִּ֨תְפַּלֵּ֔ל אֶל־יְהוָ֖ה לֵאמֹֽ
 \end{hebrew}

looks fine in the source file , but is printed reversed in the pdf 

\end{document}
```

The message error:

Package polyglossia Warning: Hebrew is not supported with LuaTeX.
(polyglossia)                I will proceed with the compilation, but
(polyglossia)                the output is not guaranteed to be correct
(polyglossia)                and may look very wrong. on input line 6.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/hebrewcal.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luabidi/luabidi.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/cal-util.def))
Module polyglossia Warning: Language nohyphenation not found in language.dat.lu
a on input line 21
Module polyglossia Warning: Language hebrew not found in language.dat.lua on in
put line 21

./esempio.aux:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.3 \select@language {italian}